# Absoluteness of complexity of sets of reals

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

In full generality, my question is:

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ and $V\subset W$. Let $A\in V$ be a set of reals with $V\models A$ is Borel. What can we say about the complexity of $A$ in $W$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^W$?

Here are some more specific questions:

For example, say we're living in $L$ and put $A=(2^\omega)^L$. It's well known that, in any outer model, the set of constructible reals is $\Sigma_2^1$. Is this sharp? Of course, it's consistently clopen, since we can always assume $V=L$, but I'm wondering about other models.

More generally, say we start off in a ground model $V$ and let $X=(2^\omega)^V$. Force to add a Cohen real $c$. In $V[c]$, every real is a limit point of $X$, because $X$ has all eventually constant sequences. So $X$ is dense, but definitely not closed. So this forcing killed the property of being closed. It's also not open, because any open set in $V[c]$ contains a generic real. Now, how ugly is $X$? Is it Borel? Projective?

One possible strategy would be to closely study the proof of Laver's theorem on the definability of the ground model, and see how complex the relevant formula is, but the parameter in it is way above the reals if I recall correctly.

Going in a slightly different direction, if we start with an infinite Borel set of reals $X\in V$, is there a forcing that unborelifies it? More precisely, is there a poset $\mathbb P$ with $\Vdash_\mathbb P \check{X} $ is not Borel? Are there "indestructible" Borel sets?

---

A reference that deals with these matters would also be appreciated. I've looked into the usual sources (Bartoszynski-Judah, Jech, Kanamori, etc) but didn't find anything.

Comment: Note that it's consistent that $\mathbb{R}^L$ is countable, hence $F_\sigma$ or $\Sigma^0_2$ depending which notation you prefer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm not following your last comment. If $\mathbb R^V$ is Borel in $V[G]$, then $\mathbb R^V$ contains a perfect subset, hence is either countable or of size continuum in $V[G]$. Why is the latter not possible?

Comment: Hm, maybe I spoke too soon - let me think for a moment ...

Comment: It's certainly the case that $\mathbb{R}^V$ can't contain a *pointed* perfect set in any reasonable sense (that is, a perfect set each of whose elements "computes," in some appropriate sense, a representation for the perfect set itself).  I thought I saw an easy trick for getting rid of the pointedness hypothesis here, but now I don't.

Comment: That said, it is easy to show that if we add $\omega_1$ many Cohen reals then the set of ground reals is non-Borel. This is because any code for a perfect subset of $\mathbb{R}^V$ would have to be added by some proper initial segment of the forcing, but then the remainder of the forcing kills of that set's closedness.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm sadly unfamiliar with the notion of pointedness. Regarding your second comment, why does every perfect set cease to be closed? I'm not seeing why, given a non-empty perfect set in a ground model, there's a Cohen generic that's a limit point of that set.

Comment: Suppose $P\in V$ is perfect. We can construe $P$ as the set of paths through a perfect tree $T\subseteq 2^{<\omega}$. There is in $V$ a homeomorphism from $2^\omega$ to $P$, and this induces an appropriate bijection $b\in V$ between $T$ and the full binary tree $2^{<\omega}$. Note that unlike the reals, both $T$ and $2^{<\omega}$ are nicely absolute. Now, in an outer model $W$ with a new real $r\in 2^\omega$, we get a new path $p$ through $T$ by pushing (the initial segments of) $r$ along $b$ - $p$ is guaranteed to be new **since $b$ is in the ground model**, so $r$ could be recovered from it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah yes, trees are things that exist, I forgot about that detail :P Thank you!

Comment: Well, *some* trees exist. :P The whole problem with my original claim is the trees that don't exist *yet*!

Comment: (BTW when I said "add $\omega_1$ many Cohen reals" I meant *via countable supports*.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is that necessary? If you use finite supports, i.e. force with $\mathrm{Add}(\omega,\omega_1)$, then lookng at nice names for reals and using the ccc we can argue that any new real must show up in an intermediate extension. Or am I glossing over something? Getting that $\aleph_1$ is preserved with countable supports forces (hehe) you to look at properness, and things get a bit dicier.

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer:

[Groszek and Slaman](https://digitalcommons.dartmouth.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3418&context=facoa) showed that if $M\subseteq N$ are transitive models of set theory that don't have the same reals and if $\mathbb{R}^M$ *countably covers* $\mathbb{R}^N$, then every perfect set in $N$ has an element which is not in $M$.

Here, $\mathbb{R}^M$ countably covers $\mathbb{R}^N$ iff for every $N$-countable $H\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$, there is some $M$-countable $G\in M$ such that $H\subseteq G$.

So after adding a Cohen real, the set of ground model reals is not Borel, since it is uncountable but doesn't contain a perfect subset by Groszek and Slaman's result.

Similarly, any uncountable Borel set in the ground model ceases to be Borel after adding a Cohen real for the same reason.

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you for the reference. If no one adds anything further in the next few days, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Actually, does the same argument not show that any analytic set ceases to be analytic after adding a Cohen real? And, with sufficient large cardinals, we'd also get that any uncountable projective set of the ground model is not projective in the extension. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're right. This argument can be applied to any uncountable members in any pointclass with the perfect set property.

Comment: Yeah, the complexity assumption in the inner model doesn't actually matter. This is really remarkable.